# AWS boto3 Chime client send x-amz-chime-bearer header

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

According to the boto3 documentation ([here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/chime.html#Chime.Client.list_channels)) for the Chime client, I can perform the ListChannels operation as such:

```
response = client.list_channels(
    AppInstanceArn='string',
    Privacy='PUBLIC'|'PRIVATE',
    MaxResults=123,
    NextToken='string'
)
```

But when performed, I get the following response:

```
[ERROR] UnauthorizedClientException: An error occurred (UnauthorizedClientException) when calling the ListChannels operation: An invalid app instance user ARN was supplied for the x-amz-chime-bearer HTTP header.
```

The docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/chime/latest/APIReference/API_ListChannels.html) state that "The x-amz-chime-bearer request header is mandatory, and you use the AppInstanceUserArn of the calling user as the value in the header."

But the boto3 documentation shows no interface to send this, as shown above.

How can I include this header or otherwise value so that my request is properly validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved using the following:

```
client = boto3.client('chime')

def add_header(params, **kwargs):
    params['headers']['x-amz-chime-bearer'] = 'appinstancearn'

client.meta.events.register('before-call.chime', add_header)
```

Comment: This works, but do you know if it's possible to modify the headers on a per-call basis? I tried just passing some extra parameters as kwargs, but then I get an error about the kwarg argument I passed being unknown.

Comment: @FrederikBaetens Looks like they added a property 'ChimeBearer' to the 'client.list_channels' method call (see first link in question) which will allow you to send the value per call. Haven't tried it myself.

Comment: That probably works, but I'm trying to modify an entirely unrelated header. Your example was useful in figuring out how to do that though.